# error io_tls flb_io_tls.c:359 NET - Connection was reset by peer

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-fargate, fluent-bit, firelens

[2020/12/10 11:44:42] [ warn] net_tcp_fd_connect: getaddrinfo(host='https://abc.amazonaws.com'): Name or service not known
[2020/12/10 11:44:42] [error] [io_tls] flb_io_tls.c:359 NET - Connection was reset by peer
[2020/12/10 11:44:42] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '1-1607600678.900285114.flb', retry in 10 seconds: task_id=0, input=forward.0 > output=es.1

getting these errors on cloudwatch while setting up ecs fargate cluster with fluent bit & firelens while routing logs to amazon elastic search. any idea what to fix this issue ?
I'm using below task definition for the setup :-

```
{
"family": "nginx-firelens-test",
"taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/ECS-firelens",
"executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/ECS-firelens",
"cpu": "512",
"memory": "1024",
"requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
],
"networkMode": "awsvpc",
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "name": "log_router",
        "image": "906394416424.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/aws-for-fluent-bit:latest",
        "essential": true,
        "firelensConfiguration": {
            "type": "fluentbit",
            "options":{
               "enable-ecs-log-metadata":"true"
            }
        },
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awslogs",
            "options": {
                "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                "awslogs-group": "firelens-container",
                "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                "awslogs-stream-prefix": "firelens"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "nginx-test",
        "image": "nginx",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 80
            }
        ],
        "essential": true,
        "environment": [],
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awsfirelens",
            "secretOptions": [],
            "options": {
                "Name": "es",
                "Host": "https://abc.amazonaws.com",
                "Port": "443",
                "tls": "On",
                "Index": "my_index",
                "Type": "fluentbit",
                "Aws_Region": "us-east-1"
                
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}